# Ninja Forms - Disabling Form Submit/Adding custom Validation in before form can be submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, ninja-forms

Essentially, what I am looking to do is prevent (disable) a form from being submit until I have been able to verify that a number that has been input into an input field, is equal to an ID of an array of posts in Wordpress.

Is this possible within Ninja Forms?

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?